# GRIB1 to GRIB2 eccodes conversion failing due to paramId = 0

Tags: grib, eccodes

So what I am trying is converting a GRIB1 file to GRIB2 containing mostly wind data.
Usually you can just change the edition to 2 and the eccodes lib does everything else.

Now the issue is that my GRIB1 file has only paramId=0 and shortName=unknown messages.
What the hell am I supposed to do? When I load it into a viewer (e.g. PredictWind Offshore) it displays just fine. Any ides on how I can convert this to GRIB2 without knowing the messages? Am I missing something?

What I already tried:

```sh
❯ grib_set -s edition=2 e1.grib e2.grib
ECCODES ERROR   :  concept: no match for paramId=0
ECCODES ERROR   :  Please check the Parameter Database 'https://apps.ecmwf.int/codes/grib/param-db/?id=0'
ECCODES ERROR   :  concept: input handle edition=2
ECCODES ERROR   :  grib_set_values[0] edition (type=long) failed: Concept no match
```

What my GRIB1 (e1.grib) looks like:

```sh
❯ grib_dump e1.grib | egrep 'paramId|shortName'
  ...
  shortName = unknown;
  paramId = 0;
  ...

❯ grib_dump dsv1.grib | egrep 'paramId' | wc -l
     679 # all unknown and 0
```

Edit:

For future readers:

I ended up not using eccodes at all. My solution now involves using PyNIO which worked great for me. It is able to read GRIB1.
For further info contact me directly.